# Install Asus USB-AC58 wi-fi adapter

Tags: networking

How to install Asus USB-AC58 wi-fi adapter drivers on ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Does it work? Why do you need drivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This device has a Realtek **RTL8812BU** chipset.
You need to install the drivers manually, there is no support "out of the box" and no official drivers.
I recommend morrowr repository for unsupported realtek USB
This is how to install the needed drivers from terminal:

1. install dependencies

```
sudo apt install dkms git build-essential
```

2. download the drivers from github

```
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702
```

3. Install the drivers

```
cd 88x2bu-20210702
sudo ./install-driver.sh
```

Your computer will reboot at the end of the process, so you might want to save any work in progress